# Good key-handling design

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-events

I've recently started using WPF for developing my applications. Now I've come to a point where I need some tips on good design when it comes to key combination handling.

This is what I'm using at the moment:

```
private void Grid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Up: PreviousLine(); break;
            case Key.Down: NextLine(); break;
            case Key.Return: NextLine(); break;
        }
    }
    else if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Return: PreviousLine(); break;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, this will start to get really ugly, really fast.

Do you have any tips which would improve the code?

Comment: This won't fix your specific problem but may prevent issues later on: you should set `e.Handled = true` only when you have effectively handled the KeyDown event.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that was just a test to see if it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMVHO there is nothing too much wrong with what you are doing, as long as it is confined to the View.

The only thing to discuss is how to smooth out the testing of key states. How you structure this is largely over to personal preference, everyone will have a slightly different take on it. Although you don't want endless `else if` statements, or lots of duplicated `switch` statements, and you don't want the handler to be 1000 lines long.

What about the following:

```
private void Grid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    bool shiftPressed = Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift;
    bool ctrlPressed = Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control;

    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Up:
            e.Handled = ctrlPressed ? PreviousLine() : false; 
            break;
        case Key.Down:
            e.Handled = ctrlPressed ? NextLine() : false; 
            break;
        case Key.Return:
            e.Handled = ctrlPressed ? NextLine() : shiftPressed ? PreviousLine() : false; 
            break;
    }
    e.Handled = false;
}
```

I created the `shiftPressed` and `ctrlPressed` bools so that i could eliminate the surrounding `if` statement (and any duplication that goes with it) and use the ternary statement instead. For this to work, you will need to return a bool from your `NextLine()` and `PreviousLine()` functions - that might seem stupid but they may not always be able to do what they should, i.e. `NextLine()` can return false if you are on the bottom row of the grid.